# How to get context of a non activity class with no Application Class in a module

Tags: android, module, android-context, android-module

I am trying to get the context to use in sharedprefs in a module of my app. The module doesn't have any Activity class extended nor does the Application Class.
Below is the code:

```
public class GetMovieCreditsUseCase extends BaseUseCase {
public static String director = "";
public static boolean loaded = false;


public interface GetMovieCreditsUseCaseCallback extends BaseUseCaseCallback {
    void onImagesUrlsLoaded(List<ImageEntity> backdrops, List<ImageEntity> posters);
}

private String apiKey;
private int movieID;

public GetMovieCreditsUseCase(String apiKey, int movieID, GetMovieCreditsUseCaseCallback callback) {
    super(callback);
    this.movieID = movieID;
    this.apiKey = apiKey;
}


@Override
public void onRun() throws Throwable {
    API.http().movieDirectors(apiKey, movieID, new Callback<GetMovieCreditsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void success(GetMovieCreditsResponse getMovieCreditsResponse, Response response) {
            ((GetMovieCreditsUseCaseCallback) callback).onImagesUrlsLoaded(getMovieCreditsResponse.getBackdrops(), getMovieCreditsResponse.getPosters());

            String json = new Gson().toJson(getMovieCreditsResponse);
            loaded = false;
            JSONObject jsonObj = null;
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JSONArray c = null;
            try {
                c = jsonObj.getJSONArray("crew");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = null;
                try {
                    obj = c.getJSONObject(i);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String A = null;
                String B = null;
                try {

                    A = obj.getString("name");
                    B = obj.getString("job");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (B.equals("Director")) {
                    Log.d("Director", "Director is " + A);
                    director = A;
                    loaded = true;

//getSharedPreferences throws error as cannotResolveMethod
                        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("director", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
                            new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
                                public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
                                        SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                                    System.out.println(key);
                                }
                            });



                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(A);
            }

            Log.d("Directing", json);


        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            if (error.getKind() == RetrofitError.Kind.NETWORK) {
                errorReason = NETWORK_ERROR;
            } else {
                errorReason = error.getResponse().getReason();
            }
            onCancel();
        }
    });
}
}
```

I tried different solutions but to no avail.
getApplicationContext, getActivity, this or MyApplication.getContext() none of them worked(all throwing error)

Comment: Send the context via constructor, but there's a bad praxis though

Comment: pass the context to the module, inject it or move the logic about context-dependent tasks out of the module

Comment: Vladyslav Matviienko, moving the logic out of module is not possible with current scenario. Any advice on how to inject it from main app to this module?

Comment: Skizo-ozᴉʞS, I get 'There is no default constructor available' error by passing context via constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented in comments, you can do this :

```
private String apiKey;
private int movieID;
private Context mContext;

public GetMovieCreditsUseCase(String apiKey, int movieID, GetMovieCreditsUseCaseCallback callback, Context context) {
    super(callback);
    this.movieID = movieID;
    this.apiKey = apiKey;
    this.mContext = context;
}
```

Then you can use :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.mContext.getSharedPreferences("director", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

But I strongly recommend to you take a look on [`Dagger 2`](https://android.jlelse.eu/dagger-2-the-simplest-approach-3e23502c4cab) to resolve this issues.

Comment: Did as suggested, but this.mContext is not getting resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> Option 1: Pass context through constructor

```
public class GetMovieCreditsUseCase extends BaseUseCase {
    private Context mContext;
    public GetMovieCreditsUseCase(Context context, String apiKey, int movieID,GetMovieCreditsUseCaseCallback callback) {
        super(callback);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.movieID = movieID;
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }
}
```

> Option 2: Define your own Application class

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name=".application.MyApplication"
        ....
```

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return mInstance.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Then call MyApplication.getAppContext()

Comment: Option 1 can't be used as it is not resolved. That is, this.mContext never shows up. Also it says 'there is no default constructor available'
Option 2 throws error while running